# What's this statement good for? _ = _;

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I found in some Angular 7 class the following code and was puzzled by it ... it isn't a Google-friendly statement to search for ... apologies :)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    SomeComponent
  ]
})
export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  _ = _; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here ... 

  // ...
}
```

Comment: The first `_` is a declaration of a fields the `_` after `=` is a variable already in scope: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+jAvDAjAKGAGwIYQjAQTBCgAsBTAJwGEQBbAB3HLFgG80Z4l4BuNAL4ZwEEJnIA6TCADmACjDkA7oWJkqtRs1ZyAlBLi6gA

Comment: `npm uninstall lodash underscore` should solve the problem.

Comment: @Reactgular yes indeed I depend on lodash in this project :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `_` is declared globally in another file:

```
export var _ = "Hello world!";
```

you may want to assign it to a property of the component class to make it available in the template:

```
import { _ } from "./external.model";

export class AppComponent {
  _ = _;
}
```

```
<div> {{ _ }} </div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x66qre?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing there is not a huge use for it but you could probably do something like the following in an Angular setting.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    SomeComponent
  ]
})
export class AnotherComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

constructor(public _: dataService){}

  _ = _;
}
```

This would just re-asign the component variable of `_` to the dataService (again as it is already assigned). I can not think of a good use case though mind.

Comment: If I comment it, then the app doesn't work anymore (it fails to render the component) so something gotta give :D